# I use telnet to connect one specific domain name on port 80. it works on personal Ubuntu but not work on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu and a local personal Ubuntu computer. I use the default VPC configuration for my EC2 instance and open EVERY port to ANY IP address for testing purpose in my security group

I can telnet Google.com 80 and Ping Google.com on my EC2 instance which means I have internet connection to the outside. I try to run

> `telnet nebraskalegislature.gov 80`

It show the the information which means the connection is no problem on port 80`Trying 164.119.9.166... Connected to nebraskalegislature.gov.`

The time out error shows on EC2 instance `Trying 164.119.9.166...telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

It has response on my own PC but doesn't work on the EC2 instance.
Here is the information in my /etc/resolv.conf

> nameserver 172.31.0.2
>
> search ec2.internal

I search Amazon EC2 forums and there is a lottt of same issues which is not free to get the answer from their customer service.

Comment: When you it doesn't work, what do you mean? What is the error message?

Comment: It show Trying 164.119.9.166...
  telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out on EC2 instance.  A good response is Trying 164.119.9.166...
  Connected to nebraskalegislature.gov. which is on my mechine

Comment: I just tried this:

      $ telnet nebraskalegislature.gov 80
      Trying 164.119.9.166...
      Connected to nebraskalegislature.gov.
      Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: @chris did you connect from a AWS host?

Comment: That first attempt was from my local machine - however, I just tried it from AWS and it worked as well.

Comment: @chris That is interesting Do you guys use the default DNS configuration and have same configuration with me in /etc/resolv.conf? Actually, I have no problem with other url but only nebraskalegislature.gov. My security group is set to open for all traffic and my gateway is default. Do you guys change the DNS service?

Comment: @chris This issue has already being boring me for a while. And I google it. I saw a lot of guys have same issue and it has to be solved from Amazon internally which is not free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys. After I test their website connection on all Amazon EC2 subnets, I think it is their internal bugs. I test two websites which are http://legislature.vermont.gov/ and http://nebraskalegislature.gov/. The result is as following:

For http://legislature.vermont.gov/

1. us-east-1b (fail)
2. us-east-1c (pass)
3. us-east-1d (pass)
4. us-east-1e (fail)

For http://nebraskalegislature.gov/

1. us-east-1b (fail)
2. us-east-1c (pass)
3. us-east-1d (fail)
4. us-east-1e (pass)

For other region like Oregon and California. There are also some issue on their subnet which is not clear. 
`Human beings create machine and also create bugs because of human nature`